# How to explicitly call the static initializer in Java?

Tags: java, initialization

So, as an example I have this JNI code:

```
/** This literally does nothing. It's purpose is to call the static initializer early to detect if we have issues before loading. */
public static void nothing() {

}

static {
    // should be loaded by CLib
    if (CLib.hasGNUTLS() == 1) {
        globalinit();
    }
}
```

I find myself literally creating a function called "nothing" to call it early if necessary, but I also want it called if it's referenced earlier or if we don't call `nothing()`. Now, I could do some nasty logic involving checking a boolean, but then you get into thread safety, and blah. I suppose you could, but it's not pretty. Is there a way to explicitly call `GNUTLS.<clinit>();`?

Comment: Just to clarify:  the purpose of the `nothing` method is just to ensure that the class has been loaded, right?  You need to load the class so that its static initializer runs, even though you don't need to do anything *else* with the class, yet, besides making the JVM load it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31027000/does-jvm-load-all-the-classes-mentioned-by-the-classpath/31028160#31028160

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The static initializer will always run before your method, because the initializer runs when the **class** is initialized. [JLS-8.7. Static Initializers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7) says (in part)

> A *static initializer* declared in a class is executed when the class is initialized ([§12.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2)). Together with any field initializers for class variables ([§8.3.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.2)), static initializers may be used to initialize the class variables of the class.

And, there is no way for you explicitly invoke any initializer (`static` or *otherwise*). However, [`Class.forName(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) says (in part)

> A call to `forName("X")` causes the class named `X` to be initialized.

Comment: Yes, I know. That's not my question. You have to reference the class for it to be loaded, and then call the static initializer, hence `nothing()` to reference the class.

Comment: You might take a look at [`Class.forName(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29). And yes, you have to reference a class for it to be loaded.

Comment: It's unclear, but I think the idea is to call a do-nothing method just to trigger classloading — not to somehow call the static initalizer (again) from *within* a method.

Comment: @JavaProphet You don't need a do-nothing method for that. Just mentioning its name is sufficient, e.g. `MyClass.class;` as a complete statement.

Comment: loading a class does not trigger initializing the class.

Comment: @ElliotFrisch The initialiser runs when #12.4.1 says so, and 'not ... under any other circumstance',  not immediately after the class is loaded'.

Comment: @EJP The Javadoc for `Class.forName(String)` clearly states that it is equivalent to `Class.forName(className, true, currentLoader)`, which according to the Javadoc, initializes the class. So it must do one or more of the things mentioned in #12.4.1 under the hood. But that's alright.

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but the `Class.forName()` answer totally made my day. I needed to re-run static initialization during unit testing to make sure that it was working correctly with multiple different properties configurations, and sticking `Class.forName()` at the top of the test forced reinitialization. +1

Comment: Some years later, [there is a way](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.Lookup.html#ensureInitialized(java.lang.Class)) to initialize a class explicitly. Though, I don’t get the original question. Calling `nothing()` does the job and is even the most efficient variant, so what was the problem?