# Does Class<SomeObject> have only one instance?

Tags: java

Does `Class<SomeObject>` have only one instance which is `SomeObject.class`?

That is to a function

`void f(Class<SomeObject> arg)`

is it possible to pass only `SomeObject.class` otherwise compile time error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always pass `null`, but barring that, yes the only valid parameter would be `SomeObject.class` which is loaded with the same `ClassLoader` as the class that contains `void f(Class<SomeObject> clazz)`.

You can have multiple distinct instances of `SomeObject.class`, but they will need to be loaded by different classloaders (otherwise they will not be separate instances, but all will refer to the same Class object).

Answer (score 8):

Yes.

As describe at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29):

> Returns the runtime class of this Object. The returned Class object is
>   the object that is locked by static synchronized methods of the
>   represented class.

But for the method `void f(Class<SomeObject> arg)` you can pass something as `void f(Class<? extends SomeObject> arg)`. Look [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641584/method-argument-extends-class-implements-interface).

Passing an `Class<? extends SomeObject arg` you can do something like that:

```
myMethod(Class<? extends BasicObject> clazz)
{
    if (!clazz.isInstance(CodeObject))
    {
        (do something different)
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! So, would that be meaningless to define
void f(Class<SomeObject> arg) as it would only accept SomeObject.class?

Comment: No! SomeObject can be extended, so If you have an extended object you can handle this on the method.

Comment: @Alex It may seem meaningless, but it can be useful in some special scenarios. For example if you had class `MyClass<T>` with `init(Class<T> clazz)` method and then you would extend from it, or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes
2. maybe You thing in this way?

   Class< ? extends SomeObject>

this is notation for class of `SomeObject` or overrides *(something wrong with syntax highlighter, don't accept ?, space between < ? is not required)*

Answer (score 0):

It does seems true that each class has only one corresponding `Class` instance, see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31028160/2158288)

Your method could also be invoked by a raw `Class` argument :) unfortunately.

```
Class clazz = AnotherClass.class;

f(clazz);
```